# Check if a mysql field exist and create if not

Tags: mysql, field, alter

I am implementing the geonames webservice, like this:

```
$( "#loc_from" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term,
                searchlang: 'ES'
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                    item.label = item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName;
                    return item;
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
         ui.item.task = 'new_city';
         $.post('/includes/router.php', ui.item , function(){

         });
         $('#id_loc').val(ui.item.gid);
         //alert(ui.item.gid);
    }
});
```

where in router.php  I have:

```
case 'new_city':
    /* comprobar si exite */
    $query = "SELECT geonameid FROM geonames";
    if(count(cache_query($query))>0){
        /* Its already in my database */
    }else{
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                    check_field($key);
            echo $key.': '.$value.'<br>';
        }
    }
    /* si no existe, dar de alta*/
    break;
```

So I would like the function `check_field($key)` to check if the geonames.$key field exists and alter the table and add it.

Is that posible? ( Also, Do you recommend this? )

Comment: Why not just add the key field in your MySQL tables before writing the code? To answer your question, yes, it can be done, but it is a bad way to do it.

Comment: Because the response returns different fields everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'geonames' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

From PHP you can do this

```
function add_column_if_not_exist($db, $column, $column_attr = "VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL" ){
    $exists = false;
    $columns = mysql_query("show columns from $db");
    while($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($columns)){
        if($c['Field'] == $column){
            $exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }      
    if(!$exists){
        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `$db` ADD `$column`  $column_attr");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, so that will check if exists. How can i alter the table and add the field if not?

Answer (score 1):

To answer one of your questions: Dynamically expanding tables is never a good idea imho.

A good way to keep your tables static is to use lookup tables.

for example:

table 1 has fields:

```
id, name
```

table 2 has fields:

```
id, name_of_dynamically_added_item
```

the lookup table looks like this:

```
id, id_table1, id_table2
```

Instead of adding a column to any table, you can add a row to table2.
For each item that should be linked to a row in table1, you can add a row to the lookup table.

This way you'll never create a table with an unforeseeable amount of columns. Also you won't have rows that are filled with mostly NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
if($row['id']=="" || NULL){
echo "id=5 do not exits";
//then create one
}
else{
echo "user exist";
}
```